# Get data for last one year from database

Tags: mysql

I want to get data records for last one year which is ordered by date. But problem is that I need the data starting from first day of that month of past year.

For example, if its 15-June-2016 today, then I need to get data from 1-June-2015.

I tried to do it with

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE
   date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 YEAR) 
ORDER BY date;
```

but Its not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `DATE_FORMAT` to force it to be the first day of the month :

```
SELECT *
FROM Table t
WHERE
   t.date >= DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL -1 YEAR),'%Y-%m-01')
ORDER BY date;
```

Comment: That's perfect mate. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem :) @arpit1611